# java freezes my computer and requires a hard reboot

Tags: java, windows-7, freeze

I have been getting semi-frequent freezes when running Java apps through NetBeans 6.9.1.  As soon as netbeans would finish compiling my app and then start to run it, my pc would freeze, i could still move my mouse and mp3s would still play in the background but i couldn't interact with anything on the screen at all, not even windows icons and the task bar.  No ctrl+alt+delete, nothing.  And if i kept clicking the mouse around 5 or so times trying to get the system to respond, my mouse would also stop responding.

For a while it seemed like cleaning and rebuilding through netbeans once per startup would fix the problem, but then it happened independent of this.

More importantly, i have got just today for the first time been able to reproduce the freeze by launching a java app outside of Netbeans, through a .bat file.

If anyone has any suggestions on resolving this issue i would much appreciate it.

When i reproduced the freeze outside of the ide i was running javaw and java's version info is:
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode

the problem is also independed of the java app i'm running.

Comment: Semi-seriously, my experience is that Java development is significantly faster on a Linux box than a Windows box.  Memory management is better and file system I/O is much faster.  Both are significant when using a Java IDE.

Comment: lol, unfortunately that's not an option.  As i can't do all the things i want in Linux, otherwise i would already be on it.

Comment: I have some more information about this problem.  It seems that using a 32 bit version of jre1.5.0_16 works (never freezes my computer) and a 64bit version of jdk1.6.0_20 freezes my computer randomly.  I have now reproduced this problem when running my app outside NetBeans using a batch file to start the appropriate version of Java with the classpath specified.  Please help.  This is extremely annoying problem.

Comment: I have the same problem... Did you find what is causing it?

Answer (score 3):

Seriously, some Java-related system lockups are related to graphics acceleration driver issues.  Try launching your Java app with 2D acceleration disabled.

Comment: hmm, good idea, but if that's the problem, how can i re-enable the graphics acceleration?  I do think you are on to something here.

Comment: If this is the real problem (big if!), you'll probably need to wait until Sun provides an Java update that fixes the problem.  Try searching the Java bugs database, using your graphics card name as one of the search keys.

Comment: Ok, thanks buddy.  Any chance i need to upgrade my graphics card driver to fix the problem?  If this is not the problem do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Coder - that's another possible workaround.  But simply running Netbeans and your Java app with 2D acceleration disabled should be good enough.

Comment: I still encounter this issue in 2020, I have my Intellij and netflix opened, then my computer hangs, so it force to to focus on serious work and not watching netflix.

Comment: So did you try running Intellij with 2D acceleration disabled?  Seriously, I'm not sure why you are telling this ... unless you have already tried the remedy suggested.  (And if you have, I don't have any alternative suggestions.)  The fact that GPUs trigger complicated bugs on some complicated setups with stress from other apps is (IMO) not at all surprising.

Comment: I would also note that posting comments on Stack Overflow is not "serious work" either :-)